# Trabalhando com 2 spinner no Android

Tags: android

Estou com dois `spinners` na mesma `Activity`. Quando eu clicar em 1 e selecionar o valor, o segundo precisa mostrar o valor relacionado a que o usuário escolheu no primeiro `spinner`.

Exemplo: Se no primeiro `spinner` ele escolher Fisioterapia, o segundo deve exibir apenas os médico de Fisioterapia.

Meu código de `spinner`

```
 //montando os spinners
    ArrayAdapter spinnerEspecialidade = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinnerEspecialidade, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    ArrayAdapter spinnerMedicos = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinnerNomeMedicos, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    spinnerEspecialidade.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinnerMedicos.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    spinnerEspec.setAdapter(spinnerEspecialidade);
    spinnerMedico.setAdapter(spinnerMedicos);

    spinnerEspec.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            selecaoEspec = i;

            if (selecaoEspec == 0){
                spinnerMedico.setEnabled(false);

            }else if (selecaoEspec == 1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Espec1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinnerMedico.setEnabled(true);

            }else if (selecaoEspec == 2){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Espec2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinnerMedico.setEnabled(true);

            }else if (selecaoEspec == 3){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Espec3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinnerMedico.setEnabled(true);

            }else if (selecaoEspec == 4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Espec4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinnerMedico.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    spinnerMedico.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            selecaoMed = i;

            if (selecaoMed == 1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nome Medico 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (selecaoMed == 2){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nome Medico 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (selecaoMed == 3){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nome Medico 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (selecaoMed == 4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nome Medico 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (selecaoMed == 5){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nome Medico 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    //FIM DA MONTAGEM DO SPINNER
```

No meu XML de strings

```
  <string-array name="spinnerEspecialidade">
    <item>Escolha a Especialidade</item>
    <item>Espec 1</item>
    <item>Espec 2</item>
    <item>Espec 3</item>
    <item>Espec 4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinnerNomeMedicos">
    <item>Escolha o Médico</item>
    <item>Nome Medico 1</item>
    <item>Nome Medico 2</item>
    <item>Nome Medico 3</item>
    <item>Nome Medico 4</item>
    <item>Nome Medico 5</item>
</string-array>
```

No meu código ele está funcionando assim:
Enquanto eu não selecionar a Especialidade o `spinner` 2 não é habilitado. Assim que o usuário escolhe a Especialidade, o `spinner` 2 é habilitado mostrando todos os "médicos". Seria nesse caso que queria usar um filtro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer que o primeiro spinner seja dinamico com o segundo,acredito que dessa forma irá funcionar :

```
spinnerEspec.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        selecaoEspec = i;

        if (selecaoEspec == 0){
            spinnerMedico.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (selecaoEspec == 1){
        spinnerMedico.setEnabled(true);

          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Nome 1");
                list.add("Nome 2");
                list.add("Nome 3");
                list.add("Nome 4");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(SuaAtividade.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinnerMedico.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


                }
```

Comment: muito obrigado deu certinho. Implementei no que eu já tinha feito aqui e está certinho agora funcionando no Firebase também. Resolveu meu problema era isso mesmo.